# Permalinks not working on MU network with domain mapping

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks, archives, domain-mapping

I'm using a theme with custom taxonomies. I want to use corresponding archives. If I try the template out on one network it works, and on another the permalink will take me to 404. The only difference between the two networks that I know of is that the one that doesn't has domain mapping, courtesy of  [this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) plugin.

Ideas for how to fix it?

(Just for the sake of it, here is how I generate the archive links: )

```
<?php foreach( get_terms('region') as $region ): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($region); ?>"><?php echo $region->name; ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Have you visited the Settings > Permalinks page?  Visiting that page will flush and recreate the rewrite rules, and that may help...

Comment: Also, can you describe the "code" you're trying out that's working on one network, but not the other?  And give more information about the permalinks that you're trying to use?

Comment: By "code" I mean the template I wrote, the only relevant part of which is how I generate the permalinks. I now include that in my post.

Yes, I tried visiting that page and also updating the permalink settings, but it did not help.

Comment: OK, after a night I visited the permalink page again and things started working. Why on earth this it did not do it the first time I visited that page and even clicked save to try to update the permalink structure I don't know. But there was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessarily a fix, but you should be able to use the [Rewrite Analyzer plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) to help you understand how WP is rewriting your links.